# How to markup or design a Multi-Level Classifieds Ads Search Form, using Twitter Bootstraps's javascript plugins?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Hello experts and experienced Web Developers,

I am working on a Classified Ads project, and I'm having some difficulties in creating the search form. I'm new to Web Design and barely understands javascript.

I am using twitter bootstrap for my theme layout and design, and I chose to use the modal.js to where I put my search form.

My problem now is, I can't find a way to display my multi-leveled listing category. It has 6 or more sub-sub categories.

Basically, what I've done so far is this. I created a tabbed navigation with drop-down button inside the modal windows. The tabbed navs hold the Parent and Sub-Category. i.e. Buys & Sell Category has "Items For Sale" and "Want To Buy" Section.

And then... Items For Sale, hold the Computers, Camera and other more. COMPUTER has a sub-category of Laptops, Netbooks and PC Components. And from those sub-category, is again broken down to child categories like: Types, Kind of PC Components (i.e. Processor, VGA Card, Chassis). From those child categories again, it has another category, i.e. Processor has a child category of INTEL and AMD.

Any idea? tips or advice on how to markup my search form? [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7Dff.png) is what I've done so far...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been days and I got no answers, And so I've explored the power to tabbable-tabs of Twiiter Bootstrap.

I solved my multi-level category search form by nesting 2 tabbable-navs with combination of drop-down select depending fields, inside a Modal Window.

This is just a design, functions is not working yet, as with the select menu dependent fields. And I don't know if this design is practical or not. As I am not yet knowledgeable in JavaScript and php/mysql.

Ok, here's what I did. The parent category, was the main Tab Navs, then child categories was in the 2nd/inner tab navs. Other sub-child categories were put in the select menu dropdowns.

And so here is the final product.
[image]